# Problem with Pythontex

Tags: pythontex

I would like to use Pythontex. I am on Mac texlive2019, python 3.7 (anaconda) TeXShop V 4.31
I followed all that was written on the documentation for the installation but impossible to have the result

```
\documentclass[12pt,french]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{pyverbatim}
import math
def racine(a):
    return math.sqrt(a)
print(racine(9))
\end{pyverbatim}
\bigskip
Résultat : 
\begin{pycode}
import math
def racine(a):
    return math.sqrt(a)
print(racine(9))
\end{pycode}
\begin{pyconsole}
var = 1 + 1
var
\end{pyconsole}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` return in Terminal?

Comment: Have you tried LuaLaTeX? Depending on your scripting needs, it might be worth it to learn. Python is my preferred language, but I use LuaLaTeX over Pythontex.

Answer (score 1):

Please download the file `Pythontex-platexmkrc.zip` from https://herbs.github.io and unzip it. That produces a platexmkrc file that contains information for TeXShop's pdflatexmk engine on how to process the files created by pythontex. Place that file in the same folder as your Source file. Then add the line `% !TEX program = pdflatexmk` to the top of your source file (it tells TeXShop to use the pdflatexmk engine to typeset the file) and typeset the file using Typeset->Typeset (Cmd-T).

NOTE: PLEASE READ THE NOTE BELOW. It is necessary to make a change to the platexmkrc file to work with anaconda3.

Comment: Sigh... There is one line in the platexmkrc file that will need editing. Drop the platexmkrc file on the TeXShop icon to open it for editing in TeXShop. Change `anacond2`  to `anaconda3` and save it.

Comment: I do it and I have this message:Running 'pythontex --interpreter python:/anaconda3/bin/python  "testpytex.pytxcode"'
------------
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: applying rule 'pythontex testpytex'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/TeX/texbin/pythontex", line 50, in <module>
    import pythontex2 as pythontex
  File "/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex2.py", line 61, in <module>
    from pygments.styles import get_all_styles
ImportError: No module named pygments.styles

Comment: Did you install the full anaconda3? I believe that pygments comes with that distribution. Do you have an Anaconda-Navigator app in /Applications? If so, open it and look under Environments for pygments. check it if it isn't already checked.

Comment: yes I have it , I don't know what to do ?

Comment: Please try to run the command `sudo /usr/local/bin/easy_install Pygments` in Terminal. It will ask for your admin password. This installs another version of Pygments where it might be found more easily.

Comment: Did you install anaconda3 only for your use or for all users of your computer?